# Android, Gradle: Create task "on fly" - Could not find method

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

Gradle 3.4:

I has some gradle task:

```
  def currentVariantName = "prod"
task runAllTestProd(dependsOn: ["test$currentVariantName" + "UnitTest", "connected$currentVariantName" + "AndroidTest"]) {
...
}
```

It's work fine.

But I want to create this task "on fly":

```
   android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def variantName = variant.getName()
    if (!variantName.equalsIgnoreCase("release")) {
        def currentVariantName = variantName.capitalize()
        def currentUnitTestName = "test$currentVariantName" + "UnitTest"
        def currentInstrumentedTestName = "connected$currentVariantName" + "AndroidTest"
        task "runAllTest$currentVariantName"(dependsOn: "[$currentUnitTestName", "$currentInstrumentedTestName]") {
            description = "Run all tests for buildType: $currentVariantName"
        }
    }
}
```

Get error:

```
Error:(181, 0) Could not find method runAllTestProd() for arguments [{dependsOn=[testProdUnitTest}, connectedProdAndroidTest], build_219ioziv1uq8hefe7aewl6fv9$_run_closure5$_closure28@69b49ec6] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.
```

Open File

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Syntax error. Change in in row **"dependsOn: ...**".

Here correct code:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
def variantName = variant.getName()
if (!variantName.equalsIgnoreCase("release")) {
    def currentVariantName = variantName.capitalize()
    def currentUnitTestName = "test$currentVariantName" + "UnitTest"
    def currentInstrumentedTestName = "connected$currentVariantName" + "AndroidTest"
    task "runAllTest$currentVariantName"(dependsOn: ["$currentUnitTestName", "$currentInstrumentedTestName"]) {
        description = "Run all tests for buildType: $currentVariantName"
    }
}
```

}